# Flutter - Firebase - Delete a document without having access to it

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to have access to notificationId once it gets created however the delete function deletes all the documents under this collection ('user-notifications').

Do you know what I need to change so I can remove only one document rather than all documents in this collection?

```
Future<String> likeAnnouncementNotification(String announcementId,
      String imageUrl, String ownerUid, String uid, List liked) async {
    String notificationid = const Uuid().v1();
    String res = "Some error occurred";
    try {
      if (liked.contains(uid)) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('notifications')
            .doc(ownerUid)
            .collection('user-notifications')
            .where("uid", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
            .get()
             .then((value) {
          value.docs.forEach((document) {
            document.reference.delete();
         
          });
        });
      } else {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('notifications')
            .doc(ownerUid)
            .collection('user-notifications')
            .doc(notificationid)
            .set(
          {
            'imageUrl': imageUrl,
            'announcementId': announcementId,
            'notificationid': notificationid,
            'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
            'type': 0,
            'uid': uid
          },
        );
      }
      res = 'success';
    } catch (err) {
      res = err.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

the only thing i see that you need to specify what notification document you went to delete add it like parameter when you call `likeAnnouncementNotification` function

```
Future<String> likeAnnouncementNotification(
    String announcementId,
    String imageUrl,
    String ownerUid, 
    String uid,
    List liked,
) async {
    String notificationid = const Uuid().v1();
    String res = "Some error occurred";
    try {
      if (liked.contains(uid)) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('notifications')
            .doc(ownerUid)
            .collection('user-notifications')
            .where("uid", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
            .get()
            .then((value) {
          value.docs.forEach((notification) {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('notifications')
                .doc(ownerUid)
                .collection('user-notifications')
                .doc(notification.id) // this is the problem you need to specify what notification document you went to delete.
                .delete();
          });
        });
      } else {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('notifications')
            .doc(ownerUid)
            .collection('user-notifications')
            .doc(notificationid)
            .set(
          {
            'imageUrl': imageUrl,
            'announcementId': announcementId,
            'notificationid': notificationid,
            'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
            'type': 0,
            'uid': uid
          },
        );
      }
      res = 'success';
    } catch (err) {
      res = err.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Ilyes! My issue is that I need to specify the notificationid that is set at the end of the function but I haven't been able to find a way.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: have good coding day @Eren